# How to create an image and then display it in psychopy builder?

Tags: psychopy

I want to display the results from my participant in the end of a task, and the easy way I can think of is to store the variables and plot it as an image and save it outside. Then I can load the image to display it. But it seems the problem is that Psychopy doesn't allow my program to run if the image does not exist when I start it. If I put a placeholder with the same image name, then my newly generated image doesn't replace the old image in the image display (although the new image is generated).

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PsychoPy-specific questions I'd really recommend you use the specific forum for the software (https://discourse.psychopy.org) rather than a general forum like stackoverflow.

In your case, it's a little hard to know what's gone wrong (no error message provided) but most likely you just failed to set the image stimulus to "set every repeat" which causes it to set that value at the start of the Routine. If you left it as "constant" then it will assume the value should be available from the start of the run.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions! That was indeed the cause of the problem, and I will be sure to switch to the psychopy forum for future questions.